# How to move select box dropdown arrow from left to right in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

i want to show the arrow of dropdown from left to right in bootstrap.
i tried a lot to solve this.

```
<select data-live-search="true" class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow">
  <option>Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
  <option>Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
  <option>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you mean from right to left ?

Comment: Up-arrow in dropdown is on the left side i want to show it on right side of select box

Comment: Can you share a fiddle of that or test site, because by default the chevron is on the right side.

Comment: i have found it we can play with class .bootstrap-select.show-menu-arrow .dropdown-toggle:after for this

Comment: great. you can close the question now.

Answer (score 1):

Override the Bootstrap Select CSS..

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .btn .caret {
left: 12px;
}
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .btn .filter-option {
text-align: right;
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/121268

Comment: i have found it we can play with class .bootstrap-select.show-menu-arrow .dropdown-toggle:after for this